# Ambulance service simulation

Tags: anylogic

I'm currently working on a project in Anylogic that is supposed to simulate a night of a public healthcare system ambulance service. Basically, I have some hospitals and each one of them has a given amount of available ambulances. When someone calls 911 an ambulance from the nearest hospital goes to the patient, and comes back. I'm having problems with the "coming back". The ambulance gets to the patient but I don't know how to tell the ambulance to come back to the hospital where it came from. The hospitals are an agent population, and I don't know how to tell the ambulances to go back to the hospital where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

in the simplest way, without taking into consideration good design you need to have in the ambulances a variable of type Hospital that holds the hospital it starts in.
The way you set up this variable depends on many things but it's so extremely basic in any anylogic model that you should easily find a way:

- it can be done if you use add_ambulance(hospital)
- you can do ambulance.hospital=hospital
- You can read it from a database

No matter what you do, on the way back you just do the moving towards an agent, which will be agent.hospital if using discrete events or moveTo(hospital) if you are using agent-based